# Error on UNOr3--> avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "/dev/ttyUSB0": No such file or directory ioctl("TIOCMGET"): Inappropriate ioctl for device

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, avrdude, clones

When I try to upload my program on the Arduino Uno Chinese clone, It says

```
 -> avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "/dev/ttyUSB0": No such file or directory
ioctl("TIOCMGET"): Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

- My Arduino Programmer: ArduinoISP
- My Arduino Software version: 1.6.8
- My OS: Linux Mint

Can you help me fix this error?

Comment: What is the serial port of your arduino?

Comment: My Serial port is /dev/ttyUSB0 . I am using Linux Mint .

Comment: if you do `ls /dev/ttyUSB0` does it show something? If so, are you a member of the `dialout` group_

Comment: Run from a terminal: `test -w /dev/ttyUSB0 || echo Error` - if it tells you `Error` you don't have permission to access the device. If it tells you nothing then your permissions are fine.

Comment: @frarugi87, when I type  'ls /dev/ttyUSB0' , it shows me a message -> /dev/ttyUSB0

Comment: @Majenko , I typed your command, it shows nothing. It executes well.

Comment: You may have done this, but...  Did you install the Linux serial port driver for the serial-port-chip on the Arduino Uno?  Also, might you have more than one USB device emulating a serial port plugged into your computer?  That is, do you see /dev/ttyUSB0, /dev/ttyUSB1, ... ect?

Comment: "Arduino UNO chinese clone"...  Also consider the possibility of your Arduino containing a counterfeit serial-port-chip (FTDI chip).  There are versions of the FTDI Windows Driver that will reset counterfeit FTDI chip USB ID's to an unusable value. And other versions of the Driver that will inject extra characters (I think "COUNTERFEIT") into the serial stream.

Comment: @frarugi87 Hi, I encountered the same problem and I did your command and received `No such file or directory
` answer from the terminal. However I was formerly able to run programs, even "blink".

Comment: @Marine1 look at the dev folder, and see if you have a ttyUSB peripheral..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be any number of different problems.  Here are several common causes:

1. You have multiple USB serial port devices connected to your computer. Try using the command `ls -l /dev/ttyUSB*` to check if your computer thinks there are more than one terminal USB device.  Disconnect all of them, then only connect the Arduino Uno.  Then repeat the check.
2. You do not have permissions.  This is tricky to check as Linux offers a flexible but complicated root, group and user permission paradigm.  **You should NOT make a habit of this**, but, for a quick check, you can try running the Arduino application as root and check if you can upload a sketch to the Arduino Uno.
3. You have a counterfeit FTDI chip on your Arduino Uno that has been [rendered useless by certain versions of the Windows FTDI Driver](http://hackaday.com/2016/02/01/ftdi-drivers-break-fake-chips-again/).  The USB IDs can get reset to useless values.  I believe the current FTDI Windows Driver no longer does this.
4. You did not install the Linux FTDI driver.  A driver is a program to abstract the hardware from the application.  In this way, different hardware can be treated the same by the application, simplifying the application.  However, the wrong driver/hardware combination may not work as expected.

Comment: FTDI drivers are not a separately installed item on most Linux distributions in the way they are with Windows.  Generally they would only need to be manually added to a very odd Linux such as might be found on an embedded or special purpose system or a custom build from scratch - the code has been part of the kernel source effectively forever and will be built and shipped as an automatically loading module in any ordinary full-featured Linux.

Comment: Don't run arduino IDE as root to test if permissions is at fault here. Run this command instead: `sudo chown root:YOURUSERNAME /dev/ttyUSB0` to give yourself access to the tty device

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved with the suggestion of [ndemou](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/24125/error-on-unor3-avrdude-ser-open-cant-open-device-dev-ttyusb0-no-such/30601#comment58820_24133):

```
sudo chown root:YOURUSERNAME /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Comment: This is a bad idea, in particular on a typical dynamically configured linux with udev or similar managing /dev nodes you will have to do it every time you connect the device.  Add your user to the appropriate group instead, which is a lasting fix.

Comment: @Greenonline - please don't make trivial edits of **bad** answers.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - Please, kindly refer to the [Review Queue](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/26648).

Comment: That means absolutely nothing.  This is a fundamentally bad answer, and that fact cannot be changed by format editing.  Additionally, even if this were a good answer, your edit would be pointless.  Such pointless edits waste everyone's time.  Kindly desist.